# Are there any multi screen size/aspect-ratio libraries for web developers?

Tags: php, javascript

There are many different viewing devices nowadays. Monitors, netbooks, slates, mobile phones, TVs, etc. and even within each of those categories they vary in size, resolution, aspect ratio, etc.

**So my question is:**
Are there any libraries for web developers with intelligent restructuring of viewable elements on the page depending on screen size, resolution, and aspect ratio? A sort of write once view by all screens kind of library?

Comment: Nice question, would be nice to have something like that.

Comment: In my opinion, "write once view by all screens" is really never going to be realistic as long as you actually care about the presentation of information & interactive elements. You should google for information on "CSS media queries".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Less Framework:

http://lessframework.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the "liquid layout" concept. Here's [one link](http://www.time-tripper.com/uipatterns/Liquid_Layout), but there is a lot of reading out there on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

As Robusto said, it sounds like liquid layout is what you want. [cssliquid.com](http://www.cssliquid.com/resources/) has a page full of good resources related to this concept. Most of these solutions are CSS based, not Javascript.

However, at some point the content will probably need to be restructured for various devices along with the layout. For example, while the same content may work for both a desktop monitor and a netbook, it probably won't be good for a small mobile phone, regardless of how the layout is changed.